# How to sort and filter queryset based on select_related in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-select-related

I have two tables in my models as show below:

```
class Coin(models.Model):
    coin_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Fundamental(models.Model):
    coin_id = models.OneToOneField(Coin, to_field="coin_id", db_column="coin_id", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    market_cap = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I want to get the top 1000 coins sorted by market cap, or market cap range is between 1000-1000000.

```
coins = Coin.objects.select_related('fundamental').order_by('ticker__market_cap')[:1000]
```

I'm writing my query like this, but it is working for some of the coins, but if any coin doesnot exists, it shows the exception like

> screener.models.Coin.fundamental.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Coin has no
> fundamental.

Does anyone will help me to filter a query in a good way

Comment: Where is your error coming from, have you shared that code? Where does "ticker" come from in your call to `order_by`? Just filter out coins without a fundamental with `.filter(fundamental__isnull=True)`?

Comment: Coin.objects.all().fundamental_set.filter(market_cap__range=(1000,1000000)).Try this

Comment: I want to get all the coins from the Coin table but sorted by market cap which is the Ticker table. Some of the coins are not available in the tickers. Can you please quote a query set to solve the problem? @IainShelvington

Comment: @IainShelvington when I start the loop on the coins, it shows some coins, after that it creates an exception, which I already showed in the output.

Comment: @Akram what is fundamental_set?

Comment: @HuzaifaZahoor it is used to filter the parent table based on child table values.('fundamental' is child table name and '_set' is django notation)